# I can not write { and [ since strg+alt+1-8 makes me exit (or tab out of) my current window

Tags: keyboard

Im using a german keyboard layout on windows where alt+strg+(7/8) write opening brackets. Im also having the same problem using the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your chosen layout is probably not the same as the true layout of your keyboard. Like you said yourself, everything seems to work fine on US Layout, whereas DE Layout gives problems (QWERTY vs QUERTZ). Either set the correct layout as default, or buy another keyboard with the layout you wish to use.

A workaround would be to use alt codes. Open notepad (or something similiar), hold down the `alt` key and type `123`, then let go of the alt key. It will type the character `{` . You can easely look up the alt codes for other characters.

Comment: So after trying out different keyboard layouts it seems the problem is that strg+alt+(1-8) makes me exit my current window in every layout. I just forgot that the AltGr key basicly just works as strg+alt and qwerty keybords just have alt keys. My problem is just finding out where you could change/remove that key combination (which seems to work in every programm i have).

Using alt codes is what im currently doing but i have to do more coding excerices for uni now and it really starts to annoy me i cant just use my regular [{ keys. :/